# how to read a routing table from a file in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to read ip addresses 128.11.56.0,255.255.255.0,117,9,45,16 from a text file in python and store them in variable.i.e subnet, mask and nexthop.

Comment: Please review the [faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It's customary to add the offending code in your project and ask specific questions regarding specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

If your file has the following format :

(line 1) : subnet,mask,nextop
(line 2) : subnet,mask,nextop
...
(line n) : subnet,mask,nextop

```
f = open(path_to_file)
lines = f.readlines()
data = []
for line in lines:
    o = {"subnet" : line.split(',')[0], "mask" : line.split(',')[1], "nexthop" : line.split(',')[2]}
    data.append(o)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but have problem when i am running this code it's showing me an error, list index out of range           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dat.py", line 10, in <module>
    words={"subnet":line.split(',')[0],"mask":line.split(',')[1],"nexthope":line.split(',')[2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
rana@ubuntu:~$

Comment: are you sure that your input file has exactly the following format:
ip1,ip2,ip3 per line ?